# Unable to add cordova plugin after cordova cli update

Tags: java, cordova, npm, cordova-cli

I have been using Cordova CLI v 6.5.0 to create  my hybrid Android app which uses a custom plugin of my own making.  The full toolchain is

- Java 1.8 SDK
- Cordova CLI 6.5.0
- NPM 4.1.2

This has always worked without an issue.  I had not upgraded to Cordova CLI 7.0.1 till today since I still supported Android 4.4 and the base version with 7.0.1 is 5.0.  Having made the decision to drop support Android v 4.4 support today I decided to upgrade Cordova CLI and immediately ran into some unpleasant surprises

- Creating a build-extras.gradle file that specifies using JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 threw up errors that claimed that some of my source code files were not compatible.  This in itself poses a problem since I make extensive use of some Java 8 features such as `try_with_resources`.
- I decided to temporarily drop back to VERSION_1_7 and got the app to complile.
- I then thought I would add my plugin to the project (expecting fully well that the system would frown at my use of Java 8 syntaxes) and ran into another unpleasant surprise which I reproduce below

  16 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
  17 error argv "H:\nodejs\node.exe" 
  "H:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "path:\to\my-plugin" "--save"
  18 error node v7.5.0
  19 error npm  v4.1.2
  20 error Invalid version: "1.0"

I do not understand these errors - perhaps someone here will be able to shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `--nofetch` to install without using the new npm install mechanism:

```
cordova plugin add path:\to\my-plugin --nofetch
```

See https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html